# $f$ extends to a smooth map $\tilde{f} : S^2 \to S^2$. - Is the proof legit?

Tags: differential-topology, solution-verification

> Let $f : \{\mathbb{R}^2 - (1, 0) - (-1, 0)\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{\bar{z}+1}$. Show that $f$ extends to a smooth map $\tilde{f} : S^2 \to S^2$.

We define $\hat{f}(\infty) = 0, \hat{f}(\pm 1,0) = \infty$.
And we show
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) & = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{\bar{z}+1} = 0.\\
\lim_{z \to \pm 1 + 0i} f(z) & = \frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{\bar{z}+1} = \infty.
\end{align*}
Hence, $f$ extends smoothly into $\hat{f}$.

Thanks~very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing what you did is correct**, you've shown it extends *continuously*, not that it extends *smoothly*. To prove that it extends smoothly you need to show that derivatives of all orders exist at the new points.

This matters. Consider the function $g:\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)= |x|$. This is smooth, and extends uniquely to a continuous function $\widehat g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by setting $\widehat g(0) = 0$, and yet $\widehat g$ is not even differentiable (let alone smooth).

---

**I say this because your notation has confused me a bit. Does $(1,0)$ mean $1+0i$? Or are you identifying $S^2$ with $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \infty$ by stereographic projection? Or what? Is $f$ even smooth?

Comment: Thank you Clive. Yes, by $(\pm 1, 0)$ I meant $(\pm 1+0i)$. It was bad notation. I'll correct it.

Comment: Hi Clive, I am not quite confident about local parametrization to show it is smooth. By any chance can you show me?

Answer (score 1):

This is not analytic.  The mapping $z\mapsto {\overline z}$ is not analytic.  Smoothly? No.